# Search for a folder using applescript

Tags: networking, applescript, directory, finder

I am trying to make a folder to go on a server, that people can add photos to and then the script sends them to the correct place, however I'm having trouble with the search part.

As you can see below in my code, the part where it finds where to send the folder to is commented out, because I have no idea what the syntax is for it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
global theWatchedFolder
set theWatchedFolder to choose folder
on idle
tell application "Finder"
    set theDetectedItems to every item of theWatchedFolder
    repeat with aDetectedItem in theDetectedItems
        set jobNumber to display dialog "Please enter the job number for this photo." buttons {"Submit", "Cancel"}
        display dialog "File detected: " & jobNumber
        --tell finder
        -- search for jobNumber in (path to desktop)
        --set jobFolder to top search result
        --end tell
        --set colourFolder to jobfolder & /colour
        move aDetectedItem to the desktop --move to colourFolder
    end repeat
end tell
if theDetectedItems is not {} then
    activate
    display dialog "test move complete"
end if
return 1
 end idle
```

Also, I am concerned that if this script is on the server, watching a folder on the server, then it won't create a pop-up for anyone who adds a file to the folder on the server. Hopefully I am wrong but if someone could confirm this one way or the other then that would be awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: Even a link to another website that tells me how to do it would be enough, I just really need to get this bit of code working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm your biggest fear. The display dialog is shown in the Finder who is targeted. You'll always address the Finder on the same machine that is running your script, unless your using remote events. If the script is running on the server, the dialog will appear in the Finder running on the server.

I have also a side note that you continuously keep running AppleScript using an idle handler to check for any updates in a particular folder. Did you know that AppleScript has memory leaks as an stay open application? It's software you don't want to run constantly on a server. It's better to start a new AppleScirpt in a new process once in a while (I prefer something like every hour) and quit the current running one. You can still use the idle handler but if the idle handler runs every 10 seconds I would quit this script and start a new one after 600 loops.

Then back to your search. Finder doesn't have a search command. Since Mac OS X Tiger Apple introduced spotlight, a meta database for finding different kind of data (files, bundles, mails,  etc). However spotlight has never been scriptable but for AppleScript only accessible on the command line using `mdls`, `mdfind` and `mdutil`. To execute commands on the command line we use the `do shell script` command in AppleScript or `do script` command for scripting the Terminal.app. Here an example of how to use with a do shell script command

```
set theFolder to choose folder
set searchKey to "the*" --use * as wild card 

findMetaDataInFolderByName(theFolder, searchKey)

on findMetaDataInFolderByName(HFSPath, searchKey)
    set options to " -onlyin " & quoted form of POSIX path of HFSPath
    set options to options & " \"kMDItemFSName == " & quoted form of searchKey & "\""
    return paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind " & options)
end findMetaDataInFolderByName
```

*note: because we're working in the shell the paths returned are posix path which can be used anywhere by prefixing the path with posix file*

But, you have mentioned that the search has to be invoked on a server. Normally when your have a server properly installed the shares are outside the application and user home folder. These folders are by default only indexed by spotlight so spotlight needs to index on the fly. In other words it's very slow compared to normal spotlight searches with are done in less than a second. So I would suggest another version of the same script as above but using `find`. Find will simply walk recursively to the given directory and print every match.

```
set theFolder to choose folder

set searchKey to "the*" --use * as wild card
findFilesInFolderByName(theFolder, searchKey)

on findFilesInFolderByName(HFSPath, searchKey)
    --the HFSPath can't have a trailing "/"
    set UFSPath to POSIX path of HFSPath
    if UFSPath ends with "/" and UFSPath is not "/" then set UFSPath to text 1 thru -2 of UFSPath
    set options to space & quoted form of UFSPath
    set options to options & " -iname " & quoted form of (searchKey) --iname is case insensitive file name match
    paragraphs of (do shell script "find " & options & " -print 2>/dev/null ; exit 0") --pipe error to /dev/null to exclude permission denied messages
end findFilesInFolderByName
```

*note: A side effect is because find will try every file while meta data search works different you'll probably find more files now because folders are included in the search as well. Just like `findMetaDataInFolderByName()`, `findFilesInFolderByName()` will return posix paths.*

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear really but at least I know now. I just wish I'd known before I told my boss I could sort it :/ Epicly detailed answer though, you more than deserve the bounty :)

Comment: From what I understand is that you want to add a photo to a folder and ask the user (client) while adding the photo to the server. You can mount invisible a network share (just mount it outside the /Volume directory). Then make your script droppable so users can drop photo(s) on your script. Then ask for a job number and then copy invisible the file(s) to the network volume. It's not what you asked but it comes close to what you eventually want.